# Mapping two object types in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, mapping, factory

I'm creating a small simulation framework in C++. I want to separate the pure simulation-related stuff from the displaying. So I have classes like:

```
class Pointer : public SimulationObject {};
class Particle : public SimulationObject {};
class LearningObserver : public SimulationObject {};
```

which all are derived from SimulationObject, but only some(!) have a visual representation:

```
class Renderable {
public:
    virtual void render() const = 0;
//may also include reference to assosciated SimulationObject
}
class PointerRenderable : public Renderable {
    void render() const { std::cout << "Render a pointer" << std::endl;
};
class ParticleRenderable : public Renderable {
    void render() const { std::cout << "Render a particle" << std::endl;
};
```

Now whenever a new SimulationObject is added to my Simulation (at runtime) I want to check, if there is a class that  renders it. If so, I want to create an instance of it. My first idea was to use polymorphy:

```
class AbstractRenderFactory {
   virtual Renderable * provideRenderable(SimulationObject * so) const = 0;
};

class ConcreteRenderFactory {
   void PointerRenderable * provideRenderable(Pointer * pointer) {
       return new PointerRenderable();
   }
   // further provideRenderable's
};
```

However using derived types when overridding methods obviously doesn't work (the base-method gets called). Also this is problematic since the function would only be partially defined.

Another idea was to provide an actual mapping of types:

```
std::map<std::type_index, std::type_index> renderTable;
```

but I can't get instances by just using the type_info. Do you have an idea?

---

**Update:** I tried using the **visitor pattern**, however I ran into similar problems. My visitor classes look like this:

```
class RenderVisitor {
public:
    virtual Renderable * visit(SimulationObject * so) {
         // I would like to have this method abstract, but I could live with this
         return 0;
    }
};

class MyRenderVisitor : public RenderVisitor {
public:
    Renderable * visit(Pointer * pointer) const {
        return new PointerRenderable();
    }
};
```

Plus the new base class for my Simulation parts.

```
class SimulationObject {
public:
    Renderable * accept(RenderVisitor * renderer) {
        return renderer->visit(this);
    }
};
```

The visit-method of MyRenderVisitor obviously isn't recognized as an override of the base-class, but I was hoping that with the *this* pointing to the actual (derived) type, the right method (that of MyRenderVisitor) would be called.

My test-scenario looks like this:

```
RenderVisitor * rv = new MyRenderVisitor();
SimulationObject * pointer = new Pointer();

Renderable * renderable = pointer->accept(rv);
renderable->render();
// renderable = 0 -> seg-fault
```

Or is just my implementation wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for visitor pattern!

Comment: As I see it the map won't help you, since at that point where you want to use it you have an object with type ''SimulationObject'', not your derived type. One possibility would be a virtual function in the renderable objects that returns the appropriate RenderableObject.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems you need double-dispatch technique, it can be implemented by applying the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).
The code to illustrate the idea:

Interface part:

```
class SimulationObject {
public:
    virtual void Accept(RenderableVisitor* visitor) const = 0;
    ...
};

class RenderableVisitor {
public:
    virtual void Visit(Pointer* pointer) const = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Particle* particle) const = 0;
    virtual void Visit(LearningObserver* learning_observer) const = 0;
}
```

Concrete part:

```
class Pointer : public SimulationObject {
public:
    virtual void Accept(RenderableVisitor* visitor) const
    {
        visitor->Visit(this);
    }
};

class Particle : public SimulationObject {
public:
    virtual void Accept(RenderableVisitor* visitor) const
    {
        visitor->Visit(this);
    }
};

class LearningObserver : public SimulationObject {
public:
    virtual void Accept(RenderableVisitor* visitor) const
    {
        visitor->Visit(this);
    }
};

class ConcreteRenderableVisitor : public RenderableVisitor {
public:
    virtual void Visit(Pointer* pointer) const
    {
        std::cout << "Render a pointer" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void Visit(Particle* particle) const
    {
        std::cout << "Render a particle" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void Visit(LearningObserver* learning_observer) const
    {
        std::cout << "Render a learning observer" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The `ConcreteRenderableVisitor` class implements logic for each leaf of `SimulationObject` class hierarchy.

Client code:

```
ConcreteRenderableVisitor visitor;
Particle particle;
particle.Accept(&visitor); // Render a particle by the visitor.
```

Client code 2 (more abstract example to proof the technique):

```
RenderableVisitor* visitor = new ConcreteRenderableVisitor;
SimulationObject* object = new Particle;
object->Accept(visitor);
```

Comment: Well, actually the abstract Visitor shouldn't be aware of any concrete SimulationParts. But I see that you'll again end up with the problem that polymorphism doesn't allow derived types as parameters for overriding methods. So I'm going to implement something similar to this.